# Blog: css broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I have some serious overlap between the text and the sidebar when viewing the blog post here http://security.blogoverflow.com .

My screen resolution is 1366x768.

Comment: I see this too - wonder what happened. Will ask.

Comment: Repro'd. Only happens at default zoom

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed. it was caused by the wide width of the `pre` code block.